# Absolute continuity of quadratic variation of continuous local martingales

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, martingales, quadratic-variation

I am interested to know if there are any simple sufficient conditions on continuous local martingale to have absolutely continuous quadratic variation. In general , we know only that quadratic variation is non-decreasing and continuous for continuous local martingales. I could not find any sufficient conditions for absolute continuity in standard text books like Karatzas and Shreve. Any help/reference is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this is a nice question but what is the motivation behind this problem?

Comment: @Lost1 : for any absolutely continuous non-decreasing processes A, we can easily associate a local martingale M having the quadratic variation A

Comment: ^ oh is this a theorem?

Comment: @ lost1 : take a Brownian Motion with $A_t$ as a time change.

Comment: @Lost1 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/612493/